# Stack of images in flatlist which can swipe horizontally

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, z-index, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to create a stack of images in react native flatlist which can swipe horizontally with the help of zindex but have no luck.
Please see the attached image for reference.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6nHE.png

PS: I've used react-native-snap-crousel but the behaviour is not same across platform.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a FlatList for this though? Based on the attached image, I'd recommend you use a View as a wrapper for the images, then make the images position absolute. Then, you can use left or right to shift their positions.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But can you tell me how to make this thing dynamic and focus the view based on swipe direction?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question.

Comment: As you have mentioned : "you can use left or right to shift their positions" . How can i achieve this ? for individual item in a dynamic array.

Comment: Could you please put up what you currently have in a snack and share the url?

Comment: Thanks bro for your response. But i've a found a library which supports this kind of behaviour and behave same across platform much better than snap-crousel.

Comment: @SaadSheikh What library did you find?

Comment: @react-native-reanimated-crousel

Answer (score 0):

You want to create Stack of images which are swipe horizontally,
then No need to use Flatlist for that you use following dependencies;
[react-native-snap-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-snap-carousel)

click on it and check various type of Examples.

[You want this](https://i.imgur.com/foMIGM2.gif)

:)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the behaviour is not same across platform the stack of image is inverted in android. I've tried multiple ways to solve it but the issue still persist.